# User-defined color implementation in windows console

Tags: c++, console, windows, enum

I have implemented an user defined colors enumerator, and if is possible I appreciate if I will get a code review.
I want to know if my implementation is correctly or must improve it.
If there exist a better alternative (color enumerator) to my code which is?

**Usage example:**

```
 HANDLE hConsole;
 setTextColor(hConsole,YELLOW_TEXT|PINK_BACKGROUND);
 std::cout << "YELLOW_TEXT|PINK_BACKGROUND";
 resetTextColor(hConsole);
```

**Colors enumerator:**

```
 enum COLOR
 {
     // Text foreground colors
     // Standard text colors
     GRAY_TEXT=8,      BLUE_TEXT,       GREEN_TEXT,
     TEAL_TEXT,        RED_TEXT,        PINK_TEXT,
     YELLOW_TEXT,      WHITE_TEXT,
     // Faded text colors
     BLACK_TEXT=0,     BLUE_FADE_TEXT,  GREEN_FADE_TEXT,
     TEAL_FADE_TEXT,   RED_FADE_TEXT,   PINK_FADE_TEXT,
     YELLOW_FADE_TEXT, WHITE_FADE_TEXT,
     // Standard text background color
     GRAY_BACKGROUND=GRAY_TEXT<<4,     BLUE_BACKGROUND=BLUE_TEXT<<4,
     GREEN_BACKGROUND=GREEN_TEXT<<4,   TEAL_BACKGROUND=TEAL_TEXT<<4,
     RED_BACKGROUND=RED_TEXT<<4,       PINK_BACKGROUND=PINK_TEXT<<4,
     YELLOW_BACKGROUND=YELLOW_TEXT<<4, WHITE_BACKGROUND=WHITE_TEXT<<4,
     // Faded text background color
     BLACK_BACKGROUND=BLACK_TEXT<<4,           BLUE_FADE_BACKGROUND=BLUE_FADE_TEXT<<4,
     GREEN_FADE_BACKGROUND=GREEN_FADE_TEXT<<4, TEAL_FADE_BACKGROUND=TEAL_FADE_TEXT<<4,
     RED_FADE_BACKGROUND=RED_FADE_TEXT<<4,       PINK_FADE_BACKGROUND=PINK_FADE_TEXT<<4,
     YELLOW_FADE_BACKGROUND=YELLOW_FADE_TEXT<<4, WHITE_FADE_BACKGROUND=WHITE_FADE_TEXT<<4
 };
```

**Set and reset functions:**

```
  BOOL resetTextColor(HANDLE h)
  {
      return SetConsoleTextAttribute(h,WHITE_FADE_TEXT);
  }

  BOOL setTextColor(HANDLE h, WORD c)
  {
      return SetConsoleTextAttribute(h,c);
  }
```

**Capture:**
  [image: Program output]

Comment: Here is full list of **Background** and **ForeGround** colors.
[Complete list of WinAPI colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49929936/6219626)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there exist a better alternative (color enumerator) to my code which is?

You should use the constants defined in a Windows header file named `Wincon.h`, which are as follows:

```
#define FOREGROUND_BLUE      0x0001 // text color contains blue.
#define FOREGROUND_GREEN     0x0002 // text color contains green.
#define FOREGROUND_RED       0x0004 // text color contains red.
#define FOREGROUND_INTENSITY 0x0008 // text color is intensified.
#define BACKGROUND_BLUE      0x0010 // background color contains blue.
#define BACKGROUND_GREEN     0x0020 // background color contains green.
#define BACKGROUND_RED       0x0040 // background color contains red.
#define BACKGROUND_INTENSITY 0x0080 // background color is intensified.
```

For example, you could write:

```
enum COLOR
{
    // Text foreground colors
    // Standard text colors
    GRAY_TEXT=FOREGROUND_INTENSITY,
    BLUE_TEXT=FOREGROUND_BLUE,
```

The answers to [C++ Win32 Console Color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17125440/49942) should be useful to you.

Alternatively here's a copy-and-paste of the equivalent .NET enum for C#, which I believe uses the same bit-values and assigns conventional color-names:

```
#region Assembly mscorlib.dll, v4.0.30319
// C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll
#endregion

namespace System
{
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies constants that define foreground and background colors for the
    //     console.
    [Serializable]
    public enum ConsoleColor
    {
        // Summary:
        //     The color black.
        Black = 0,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark blue.
        DarkBlue = 1,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark green.
        DarkGreen = 2,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark cyan (dark blue-green).
        DarkCyan = 3,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark red.
        DarkRed = 4,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark magenta (dark purplish-red).
        DarkMagenta = 5,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark yellow (ochre).
        DarkYellow = 6,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color gray.
        Gray = 7,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color dark gray.
        DarkGray = 8,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color blue.
        Blue = 9,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color green.
        Green = 10,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color cyan (blue-green).
        Cyan = 11,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color red.
        Red = 12,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color magenta (purplish-red).
        Magenta = 13,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color yellow.
        Yellow = 14,
        //
        // Summary:
        //     The color white.
        White = 15,
    }
}
```

---

If you're going to define your own enum then use it in your function declaration, i.e.:

```
BOOL setTextColor(HANDLE h, COLOR c)
```

... not ...

```
BOOL setTextColor(HANDLE h, WORD c)
```

I'd usually use mixed-case e.g. `Color` instead of `COLOR` for an enum; and I'd worry that it's already been defined in a header file.

Also I'd split it into two parameters instead of doubling the number of enum values, for example:

```
BOOL setTextColor(HANDLE h, ConsoleColor foregound, ConsoleColor background)
{
    WORD color = foregound | (background << 4);
    return SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, color);
}
```